# Configuration Error: deployment source '(projectname): war exploded' is not valid

Tags: java, sql, spring, intellij-idea

I have a project that runs Spring and I am using IntelliJ as the compiler. I started building the project in Ubuntu but I was having problems viewing my database edits so I switched to Windows and lost my Ubuntu partition (due to some other unrelated error). I am trying to reset up my project in Windows but I can't get it to compile properly.

I have tried redownloading IntelliJ, restarting my computer, clean installing maven, and searching everywhere for a solution. I found a link on IntelliJ's website but they never actually address a solution to the problem ( http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/436515 ). I started to try the unfinished advice to "remove all artifacts selected for deployment from the list and then add them again" but I cannot figure out how to add them again once deleted.

Additionally, I keep seeing the error "Configuration Error: deployment source '(projectname): war exploded' is not valid"

Any advice or tips to what I could try or am doing wrong would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

This will happen when you remove an artifact that is already set in the configuration. You can see the artifact is red in the configuration:

[image: Artifact that is missing]

To solve it, just removed the missing one and add another valid artifact.

Comment: Helped me a lot

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. Now, I just need to restart Tomcat

Comment: The artifact was there in my case (nothing was red). I just deleted it, saved, and readded the same artifact again - then it worked.

Answer (score 13):

Edit Configurations - deployment add your artifacts.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you can try the following process.

1.Open Project Structure add an artifact (web application:exploded) from modules, select your module, add it:
[image]

2.Build Artifacts [(top menu) - build - build artifacts - build]

3.Edit Configurations - deployment add your artifacts

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue for me.

I do not know why, but for some reason my .war file got corrupted. I went to Project Structure > Artifacts, deleted my old artifact (which IntelliJ already highlighted red) and added it again.

Comment: Worked but needed to re-add the artifact in the deployment settings, not in the project structure.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reason it may happen is, you have restructured your project packages. In that case you have to re-adjust your run configuration in the intelliJ. Edit Configuration > Deployment (On your server) > Delete the existing one and add newly build war again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem. The reasons for each person may be different. I was running fine yesterday, but this error popped up this morning.
My solution was to find the temporary deployment directory of Tomcat in IDEA (for example, in this location: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\tomcat) and delete everything in it. After that, I restarted it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, i faced similar issue. I made a Spring MVC webapp using IntelliJ on Ubuntu(Running on a VM).
Later on when i tried to run it on Windows IntelliJ, it went bonkers... so to fix that...
I deleted all IntelliJ  configuration files, *.iml target WARs
and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who restructured and/or moved a lot of files; a rebuild will fix this error

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you remove an artifact that is already set in the configuration. You can see the artifact is red in the configuration,
you should remove the red one and add the correct one.

Comment: Duplicate answer

Answer (score -2):

**Build Artifacts** (Top menu - Build - Build Artifacts):

[image: (top munu) - bulid - build artifacts[show image2]